# Why am i logged as root when i use normal users credentials?

Tags: centos, gnome

I've installed GNOME on my CentOS 6.8 server, i log in via NOMACHINE NX software from windows. Even if i use my normal user and password when i log in i'm root. I don't want to be root. I must have made some change on the linux config to get this behavior. I know i added my user to groups like "admin", "root", and "wheel" before because i was tired of being asked the password all the time. I edited sudoers and uncommented

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But at some point i realized i wasn't my user anymore, even if i logged in with my credentials i was always root.
Now i'm trying to get back as a normal users and i can't.

I commented back sudoers. My sudoers.d is empty.
I've removed all groups from my user except the user group.
I tried `sudo su` via ssh and i get:

```
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I don't understand what else can i do to log in as normal user on GNOME?

---

Requested info:

**grep myuser /etc/passwd**

```
myuser:x:502:502::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

Requested info 2:

**grep root /etc/passwd**

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
```

**# .bash_profile**

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

**# .bashrc**

```
# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

**# /etc/bashrc**

```
# System wide functions and aliases
# Environment stuff goes in /etc/profile

# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
        fi
        ;;
    screen)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default
        ;;
      esac
  fi
  # Turn on checkwinsize
  shopt -s checkwinsize
  [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
  # You might want to have e.g. tty in prompt (e.g. more virtual machines)
  # and console windows
  # If you want to do so, just add e.g.
  # if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  #   PS1="[\u@\h:\l \W]\\$ "
  # fi
  # to your custom modification shell script in /etc/profile.d/ directory
fi

if ! shopt -q login_shell ; then # We're not a login shell
    # Need to redefine pathmunge, it get's undefined at the end of /etc/profile
    pathmunge () {
        case ":${PATH}:" in
            *:"$1":*)
                ;;
            *)
                if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                    PATH=$PATH:$1
                else
                    PATH=$1:$PATH
                fi
        esac
    }

    # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell.
    # Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
    # You could check uidgid reservation validity in
    # /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
    if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
       umask 002
    else
       umask 022
    fi

    # Only display echos from profile.d scripts if we are no login shell
    # and interactive - otherwise just process them to set envvars
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            if [ "$PS1" ]; then
                . "$i"
            else
                . "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
            fi
        fi
    done

    unset i
    unset pathmunge
fi
# vim:ts=4:sw=4
```

Comment: Hey, On GNOME on the top right corner it says root. If i click system it says log out root. On the desktop instead of my user's folder i see root's folder and i can browse it.

Comment: ... Did you at some point alter your UID to 0 in /etc/passwd ?

Comment: I bet the UID for your user is 0. `grep <your-username> /etc/passwd` and add that output to your question.

Comment: I don't think i did i added the output of that command to my question, please let me know if you have more ideas or tests to run.

Comment: What if you `grep root /etc/passwd`? I would also look in /var/log/secure for clues. Maybe something in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (or `/etc/bashrc` and other system wide profile files)  is executing a `su` or `sudo`. The root account does have a password, correct?

Comment: Hi, i've added those files content to the post. /var/log/secure has millions of entries about failed login attempts as root, and my successful ones. The root account has a password.

Comment: hmm maybe this isn't linux problem at all but how nomachine is setup? I don't have saved sessions i deleted them all but still, maybe nomachine config is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Linux, it's NoMachine server config, specifically:
server.cfg file, if you set:

```
CreateDisplay 1
DisplayOwner root
```

You will be root on GNOME, Reference: https://www.nomachine.com/TR04N06814&tn=DisplayOwner

Apparently i forgot about that change i made myself...